# Proving the infimum of A:=(m,n) is m

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

I'm just practicing doing proofs that involve supremums and infimums to better understand them for my elementary analysis class. Could someone please correct any errors in my proof. I found this proof [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proofs-regarding-the-supremum-or-infimum-of-a-bounded-set). The proof in question is example 2. I'm just wondering if I could prove the second part of the proof using contradiction.

$A=(m,n)$ implies $\{x\in R: m\lt x\lt n\}$ In addition, we can see that there is no minimum or maximum since this is an open interval.

Now, in order to prove that $\inf(A)=m$, I need to
1) Show m is a lower bound: this is done by using the definition of what the set A is. By definition: $m\lt x:\forall x\in A$

Thus, m is a lower bound of A.

2) By contradiction: assume $m_0$ is the largest lower bound of A which implies that $m_0\gt m$ and $m_0\lt x:\forall x\in$ A. Then, $m\lt m_0 \lt x \lt n$ $\Rightarrow$ $m_0 \in A$. Since $m_0\in A \Rightarrow \frac{m+m_0}{2}\in A \Rightarrow \exists$ x such that $x\lt m_0$. Which is a direct contradiction to $m_0\lt x$. Thus, m is the largest lower bound.

Since these two conditions were satisfied, $\inf(A)=m$

As always, thank you for your time.

Comment: $m_0$ being largest lower bound isn't an erroneous statement that will lead to a contradiction as $m_0 = m$ could be a possibility.  If $m_0$ is the largest lower bound of A does not imply $m_0  > m$; it implies $m_0 \ge m$.

Comment: I now see that, thanks!  Since $m_0\ge$ m implies $m_0=m$ wouldn't that give $m\lt m$ which is a false proposition. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: You proof by contradiction would work.  Just need to say either "assume m is not glb but m_0 is" or "assume there is a lower bound m_0 > m".  Both of those statements will lead to the contradiction you want-- namely any $x|m <x <m_0$ means $x \not \in (m,n) $ which is impossible.

Comment: Just for clarification, is x|m x divides m or is it something else entirely?

Comment: In this case I meant "such that" .  Divides has nothing to do wit it as we aren't dealing with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to just do definitions.

$A=(m,n)=\{x\in \mathbb R | m <x <n\} $.

1) for all $x \in A $, $x <m $ by definition.  So $m$ is lower bound.

2) If $r>m $ then $m < \min (n,r) $ and by the archimedian principle  there is an $y$ so that $m<y <\min(n,r)$.  (If you want you can set $y=\min (\frac {m+r}2,\frac {m+n}2) $... but you don't have to.

Then $m<y <\min (n,r)\le r $ so $r$ is not an lower bound.  So $m $ is greatest lower bound.

If you want to do a prove by contradiction, you can do 2 differently.

2') Suppose $m $ is not greatest lower bound.  Then there is an lower bound $m_0; m <m_0$ (it doesn't have to be the greatest lower bound).

Let $y $ be so $m < y <m_0$. The for any $x\in A $ we have: $m_0 \le x; m <x < n ; m < y <m_0$.  So $m <y <n $.  So $y \in A $.  This contradicts $m_0$ is lower bound of $A $.

So $m $ is greastest lower bound.

A third way and fourth use the theorem:  if $x \le y \le x+\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then $y=x $.  (Have you proven that?  If you haven't you should.  It's a good exercise.)

2'')  $m $ is a lower bound.  So if $m_0$ is greatest lower bound then $m \le m_0$.  Let $(n-m) > \epsilon >0$.  Then $m <m+\epsilon < n $ so $m+\epsilon \in A $.  So as $m_0 $ is lower bound $m_0 \le m+\epsilon$.  So $m\le m_0\le m+\epsilon $.

So $m=m_0$

2''')  let $m_0$ be greatest lower bound. $m_0 <n $ as $m_0 <x <n $ for all $x\in A $. Let $\epsilon >0$.  $m_0 - \epsilon < \inf A=m_0$ so $m_0-\epsilon \not \in A $ and $m_0-\epsilon <m_0 <n$.  So $m_0-\epsilon \le m $.

And as $m $ is lower bound $m\le m_0$.  So $m_0-\epsilon\le m\le m_0$.

So $m=m_0$.